# How to replace a div content from within the content and navigate inside a tab?

Tags: ajax, html

Inside a tab, I have a few radio buttons and a div. When clicking on a button, I replace the div by a specific content in Ajax. It works fine. What I want to do really is to navigate inside the tab, ie from within the div click a link that will change the content of the main tab div and eventually use the history to go pack to the previous page inside the tab.

Is it doable? Any clue where to look?

TIA,

JF

Comment: What do you mean by a "tab" here?  I'm assuming you're using a Javascript framework to implement a tabbed UI.  If so, which one?  Could you provide your code?  If changing tabs doesn't change the URL, then you probably can't use the history to go back, but there are probably other ways to do it...no way to tell without the code though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jQuery Ui tabs. Navigating from one tab to another works fine (and history with it. Inside the tabs I have several buttons, once clicked, it changes a div content inside the tab itself.

```
<div id="tabs-10">
            <div id="acQual" class="accordion"> <!-- Catalogue -->
                <h3><a href="#">Verres</a></h3>
                <center>
                <div>
                    <form>
                    <div class="radiobouton">   <!-- barre de boutons -->
                        <input type="radio" id="radiov1" name="radio" onclick="shows('resVerresSimples','scripts/getcat.asp','q','1')" /><label for="radiov1">Verres Simples</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="radiov2" name="radio" onclick="shows('resVerresSimples','scripts/getcat.asp','q','2')" /><label for="radiov2">Verres Spéciaux</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="radiov3" name="radio" onclick="shows('resVerresSimples','scripts/getcat.asp','q','3')" /><label for="radiov3">Verres Feuilletés</label>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                <br>
                <div id="resVerresSimples"><img src="images/browser.png"></div>
                </center>
```

My problem is that inside my getcat.asp, I have links that I want to open in the resVerresSimples div...